# Animating changes in pages background color of a uiscrollview while user is swiping, synchronizing change in background color with offset change

Tags: colors, background, uiscrollview

any hint on achieving this, ie, animating changes in pages background color of a uiscrollview while user is swiping, synchronizing change in background color with offset change, back and forth ?

Regards,

j.

Answer (score 0):

To make changes in real time while scrolling you should use UIScrollView delegate method:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

If you create 2 view controller and add their view as subviews of a scroll view, set the delegate property of your scroll view and add this code inside the delegate:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    CGFloat offset = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
    CGFloat factor =  offset / scrollView.bounds.size.width;

    _leftVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:factor saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0 alpha:1.0];
    _rightVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.3 saturation:1.0 brightness:factor alpha:1.0];

}
```

It just change the background color, but you can do everything you need synchronized with the scroll view offset.